# sed does not print line when using address format

Tags: sed

sed does not print line 1 to line 545.The result of the following command is empty resultfile.txt. Can someone say what should be the correct command?

```
RESULT=545;sed -n '1, $RESULT p' Configuration.txt > resultfile.txt
```

Comment: double quote to interpret variable + no space after first `,`

Answer (score 2):

The above is not a `sed` issue, but rather a shell issue: you used single quotes, which inhibit variable expansion.

```
$ echo '$PWD'
$PWD
$ echo $PWD
/tmp
$ echo "$PWD"
/tmp
```

Either no quotes at all, or double quotes, allows the shell to expand variables.  (No quotes at all means the shell expands *everything*; double quotes inhibit globbing, redirections, and such.)

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes so that $RESULT is expanded:

```
RESULT=545;sed -n "1, $RESULT p" Configuration.txt > resultfile.txt
```

By the way, the following would be simpler:

```
head -$RESULT Configuration.txt > resultfile.txt
```

And, if your file is big, this will quit as soon as you reach line 545 and be more efficient:

```
sed ${RESULT}q Configuration.txt > resultfile.txt
```

Comment: Good point on using `q` to exit `sed` (although when using `sed` to edit stdin, beware of broken pipe errors).